# understanding proof of theorem(1) of greatest common divisor in 'higher algebra' by bernard and child?

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

[extract from book 'higher algebra' by bernard and child](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODulf.jpg)

i understood the 2 sentences in proof(see image in link above).

> since a = bq + r, every common divisor of b and r is a divisor of a ;
>   and, since r = a - bq, every common divisor of a and b is a divisor of
>   r.

but i don't see how they prove the theorem.

can you help me understand this proof from authors point of view?

Answer (score 1):

Just write down, what it means for a number $d$ to be a divisor:

- $d | b,r \Rightarrow b=kd,\; r=ld \Rightarrow a = bq+r = kdq+ld =d(kq+l) \Rightarrow d|a$
- similarly the other case

Edit after comment:

The author uses the following fact:

- Given two sets $A,B$. Then $A= B \Leftrightarrow A\subset B \mbox{ and } B\subset A$

Now apply this fact to the two sets:

- $A = \{d \in \mathbb{Z}| d|b \mbox{ and } b|r\}$
- $B = \{d \in \mathbb{Z}| d|b \mbox{ and } d|a\}$

Comment: i understand that as i mentioned in question. but i don't see how these 2 statements prove the theorem.

Comment: @Akaleti: I added some more info on set equality. This is used implicitly in the proof.